# how to edit many-to-many related data in EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, many-to-many, blazor-webassembly

I have a many-to-many relationship, I'm using asp net core, ef, and blazor and I want to edit my model that has that relationship, but I don't know how to do it, with models without a many-to-many relationship I haven't had problems editing, but with this type of relationship I don't know how to do it, previously I used automapper but in this project I can't use it so I map the data manually, also I get this error: :

> Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'key')

this is my model:

```
public class Level
{
   public int LevelId { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public virtual List<LevelInstallationType> LevelInstallationTypes { get; set; } = new List<LevelInstallationType>();
}


public class InstallationType
{
   public int InstallationTypeId { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public virtual List<LevelInstallationType> LevelInstallationTypes { get; set; }
}

public class LevelInstallationType
{
   public int LevelId { get; set; }
   public int InstallationTypeId { get; set; }
   public virtual Level Level { get; set; }
   public virtual InstallationType InstallationType { get; set; }
}

[HttpPut]
public async Task<ActionResult> Put(Level level)
{
    var oldDB = await _context.Level                        
                        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == level.Id);

    oldDB.Name = level.Name;
    oldDB.LevelInstallationTypes = level.LevelInstallationTypes; 
    context.Entry(oldDB).State = EntityState.Modified; 
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync(); 
    return NoContent();
}
```

Comment: Please provide your database structure and the value of `level`. There may be a value in your `level` that is not populated causing an error.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to add null somewhere. Debug and check the data.